# Heroku connect customization

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect, heroku-enterprise

Currently i did not find any solution in which we can create/define a logic which we can write in Heroku connect to restrict this sync to certain records in s table. 
Example: I have a custom object in which I have 2 recordtypes. I only want to sync 1 record type records to Heroku through connect. 
Is there a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku connect does not have this kind of configuration anywhere in the dashboard. The reason for that probably is because the number of records to be synced should be driven by the user with whom the Heroku authentication is done.

If you want a specific condition to be fulfilled, I suggest you create an API user which has access to only the records you want to sync and use that as Heroku connect authentication user.

You will likely need to create a new user with a new profile, remove View All and Modify All from objects and View All Data/Modify All Data from the profile. Then share the records fulfilling specific criteria with that user.

Comment: Manjit we tried this logic and as we have all full sandboxes and post refresh even this isn't helping.